# Google Maps API - Want to show postcode on map - JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I'm currently working on a google maps module which takes the postcode from the database (MySql) and displays it on screen. It's currently using a HTML form submission button but I would ideally like to remove that. Would anyone be able to take a look and show me what steps I would need to take to make this happen.

thanks

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "You aren't logged in, please do so below<br>";
    include('loginform.php');
    exit();
}

?>
<!doctype html><head>
  <title>front</title>
  <style>
p {
    color: white;
}
      #map
        {
          height:400px;
          width:400px;
          display:block;
        }
.element {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 51px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.text {
    color: white;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button {
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
background-blend-mode: screen;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
      }
      .content {
          position: relative;
          top: 25px;
          width: 320px;
          margin: auto;
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDdfR_iH3dKB3ghSFhyDvfTeoA53c6PPGg"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

          function getPosition(callback) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;

            geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, function(results, status) 
            {   
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
              {
                callback({
                  latt: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                  long: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                });
              }
            });
          }

          function setup_map(latitude, longitude) { 
            var _position = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 16,
              center: _position
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: mapOptions.center,
              map: map
            });
          }

          window.onload = function() {
            setup_map(51.5073509, -0.12775829999998223);

            document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
              getPosition(function(position){

                var text = document.getElementById("text")
                text.innerHTML = "Marker position: { Longitude: "+position.long+ ",  Latitude:"+position.latt+" }";

                setup_map(position.latt, position.long);
              });
            }
          }
      </script>   
   </head>

<?php
include('header.html');
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $con = ***
    if (!isset($con)) {
        echo "Connection to Aurora System failed.";
    }  

if(isset($_POST['shop_id'])){
    $shopid = $_POST['shop_id'];
} else {
    die('Shop not selected');
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>shopoptions</title>

<body>
  <div class="content" align="center">
  <p class="text text-3"><?php $query2 = "SELECT shopname, contactname, streetaddress, streetaddress2, city, county, email, phonenumber, postcode FROM shops WHERE shop_id = '$shopid'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo $row2['shopname'] . '<br>' . $row2['contactname'] . '<br>' . $row2['streetaddress'] . '<br>' . $row2['streetaddress2'] . '<br>' . $row2['city'] . '<br>' . $row2['county'] . '<br>' . $row2['postcode'] . '<br><br>' . $row2['email'] . '<br>' . $row2['phonenumber'] . '<br><br>';
        $postcode = $row2['postcode'];
    } ?></p><br>
          <form action="javascript:void(0)" id="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Show me"/>
      </form>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="text"></div>


    <br>

  <form action="orderselect.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shopid; ?>" name="shop_id">
  <button class="button">View Orders</button>
  </form><br>
  <form action="FUCKORDER.PHP" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shopid; ?>" name="shop_id">
  <button class="button">Create Report</button>
  </form><br>
  <form action="competitors.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shopid; ?>" name="shop_id">
    <button class="button">POS / Competition</button>
  </form><br>

  <a href="front.php"><button class="button">Go Back</button></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well....what do you want to do instead..?

Comment: Doh! Would help if I stated that haha. I want to be able to take the post code from the mysql database, and then have the be used to automaticcly show where it is on the map

Answer (score 1):

You have to take postcode as well as country name so this will work for many country. If you want only Post code to be used, then you have to put restriction for searching within specified country only.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/zL1vb4wn/) demo

Idea is to get the data that is post code + country from mysql database and put it in hidden field value

`<input id="pin_country" type="hidden" value="560038, india">`

Then the call JavaScript function `window.onload = codeAddress()`

This will show the place on the map

So code

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
codeAddress = function() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var address = document.getElementById('pin_country').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        zoom: 16,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
        },
        center: results[0].geometry.location,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        draggable: false,
        title: 'My Title'
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

window.onload=codeAddress()
```

If you want that to use only post code then above code is modified

`<input id="pin_country" type="hidden" value="560038">`

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address,
    componentRestrictions: {  /*this adds restict to specific country*/
            country: 'IN',
          }
  }, function(results, status) {...})
```